# Looping through properties in the constructor

Tags: c#

Is there a way to select all properties of a specific type and give it a default value from inside the constructor?

I have 32 `int32` properties with backing fields in a class, and i want to default all of them to -1 in the constructor, any other way than writing them all in the constructor?

Comment: You can set default value to the backing field directly: `private int _myField = -1;`

Comment: Are you sure it even makes sense to have 32 properties in a single class? That's *usually* a sign that it would be worth breaking them up into smaller types. Can you give examples of what these properties mean?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: That doesn't work if they're automatically implemented properties, of course.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek that means writing this line 32 times for each field, thats why i asked the question

Comment: I'm with @JonSkeet here - maybe a collection of these fields if they're related?

Comment: @JonSkeet the design is pretty good, its a mathmaical game so i cant change much in it

Comment: Could you just `foreach (var p in this.GetType().GetProperties()) p.SetValue(this, -1);` in ctor? Had you also considered using an array?

Comment: @JonSkeet He said, that he had *properties **with backing fields***. @user1492051: But your question states, that you already have all these backing fields, so it's just about adding `= -1` to the declarations.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek i have forgotten to do it when i declared the fields, that means i have to wite = -1 an go on a ctrl+v rage

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Ah, I missed that. Yes, in that case I'd do that.

Comment: @user1492051: How long would it have taken you to hit Ctrl-V 32 times compared with the time spent on this question? I'm still dubious about your claim that the design is good, but unless you provide more details we can't really suggest alternatives.

Comment: @JonSkeet i don't know but i find it useful, suppose you had a class that represents user rights, all properties are boolean, i would have multiple constructors, one constructor for the Admin user rights which sets all values to true

Comment: @user1492051: I wouldn't have a *constructor* for admin user rights. I might have a static method to return an appropriate instance, but even so I wouldn't want to just set all backing fields to `true` automatically. That assumes that all of them have the same "sense", aside from anything else. (I'd probably use a flags enum instead, mind you...)

Comment: @JonSkeet i prefer writing less code and thinking linearly after all i am just a noob, i'll probably be a fisherman but i enjoy programming!

Comment: @user1492051: I prefer to have it *obvious* what the code will do - and giving each field an initial value at the point of declaration is really simple. Much, much simpler than using reflection as per the accepted answer - and also less code, in fact.

Comment: @JonSkeet i require different default values, sometimes i want i to be -1 and somtimes -2, sending the default value for a specific type is the better option, i'll just send the default value of a specific type to the constructor and done! in case you wonder why am i not using a list its because alot of operations are done on those properties every second and for example prop29*prop30*prop31 is faster than x[29]*x[30]*x[31] as far as i know

Comment: @user1492051: Wow, you're using micro-optimization to justify having 32 fields? Have you even measured the performance yet? Do you have *any idea* how slow using reflection (as per your accepted answer) is compared with setting fields directly? These decisions just get worse and worse, as far as I can tell...

Comment: @JonSkeet wait i'll test the game performance on a list a on sperate properties and put the timing here, its a touch screen game with squares, and things change, appear and disappear quickly

Comment: @user1492051: How quickly is quickly? Any difference introduced by an array access would be *miniscule* - unless your game has a frame rate of about 10,000qps, I'd be amazed if it were even detectable...

Comment: @JonSkeet Elapsed Properties Initialization With reflection 32 prop 00:00:00.0020141
Elapsed Array Initialization int[32] 00:00:00.0005603
Roll , Time Elapsed 00:00:00.1127108 Roll with array , Time Elapsed 00:00:00.1602841 , in the game roll properties win but i think its not worth it the array is fast enough, thanks for the enlightment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might take a bit of refinement, but something like this would do the trick.

```
class A{
    public A()
    {
        var props = this.GetType()
                .GetProperties()
                .Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(int));
        foreach(var prop in props)
        {
            //prop.SetValue(this, -1);  //.net 4.5
            prop.SetValue(this, -1, null); //all versions of .net
        }
    }
    public int ValA{get; set;}
    public int ValB{get; set;}
    public int ValC{get; set;}
}
```

Comment: maybe `this.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(int))` so not to afraid add another properties?

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: yes indeed.

Comment: p => p.PropertyType == typeof(int) && p.CanWrite

Comment: my approach has one disadvantage: `long` and `float` properties will be ignored, which may not be desired. In perfect word, you would write `new[]{typeof(int), typeof(decimal), typeof(long)}.Contains(prop.PropertyType)`

Comment: @plinth this quickly becomes a messy linq indeed

Comment: @spender `prop.SetValue(this, -1);` , both answers have this part but the SetValue requires 3 arguments

Comment: I think anything more rapidly becomes guesswork. That's why I stated "bit of refinement"

Comment: think a for loop is needed because the third argument is index!

Comment: Ah. The 2 parameter version is not available for .net < 4.5. Simply set third param to null as per the documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb5dd1f1.aspx

Comment: You don't have to check for CanWrite, but if you have a get-only property, this will throw an exception.  Quite honestly, I would consider putting a custom attribute on the property [DefaultValue=-1] then write a static utility method that checks for that prop and sets it to the value.  Finally, write a unit test for my project that verifies that all objects with properties with that attribute meet that requirement of having a public setter.

Answer (score 1):

IF you want to do this:

```
void Main()
{
    var test = new Test();
    Console.WriteLine (test.X);
    Console.WriteLine (test.Y);
}
```

Class Definition:

```
 public class Test 
 {
       public int X {get; set;}
       public int Y {get; set;}

       public Test()
       {
              foreach(var prop in this.GetType().GetProperties())
              {
                    if(prop.PropertyType == typeof(int))
                    {
                          prop.SetValue(this, -1);
                    }
              }
       }
 }
```

Output:

> -1
>   -1